# math font for xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex

I'm looking for a math font to be used in [xelatex](/questions/tagged/xelatex). Right now I use `Asana Math`, which actually looks nice, but is too bold for my purposes. For normal text I use the `Roboto` font, if I write

```
normal vs. $\mathsf{math}$
```

I get:

[image]

I tried many different math fonts, but they all look bolder than the normal font. Is there either a way to tell [xelatex](/questions/tagged/xelatex) to use a thinner font or is there a math font which is thinner innately?

Comment: Roboto font is available under Apache License from here: https://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html

Comment: This does not address my question.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't but you didn't provide a source for the font in your question. I'm pretty sure that not everybody has Roboto installed by default. Also this is a comment rather than an answer and comments are not always on topic. Furthermore you could just read the [`mathspec`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/xetex/latex/mathspec/mathspec.pdf) manual.

Comment: You really ought not use *any* sans serif font for 'normal text'. It is harder to read than a serif when used for text blocks. (Fine for headings and titles if it matches the body font.)

Answer (score 6):

Just use the scaling feature of `fontspec` (inherited by `unicode-math`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Roboto}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Asana Math}

\begin{document}
normal vs. $\mathsf{math}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, mixing Asana Math for math and the Roboto font doesn't seem a good choice; a math intensive document shouldn't be typeset in a sans serif font for which there's no real matching math font available.

Comment: **No** document should be typeset entirely in sans serif regardless of whether it is maths-intensive or whether a matching maths font is available ;).